# Android Blank Grid Items

Tags: android, gridview

I am working on an app that display's WhatsApp status images in GridView. while launching the app it shows images correctly but shows some blank griditems. I know this blank griditem because of video files in directory, but I don't know how to separate the image files from videos. I used bitmap to show images on grid. So it shows blank gridview. I need only images on gridview.

Here's my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String[] FilePathStrings;
private String[] FileNameStrings;
private File[] listFile;
GridView grid;
GridViewAdapter adapter;
File file;
String extension = ".jpg";
String TAG;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Locate the image folder in your SD Card
        file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/");


    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        listFile = file.listFiles();

        // Create a String array for FilePathStrings
        FilePathStrings = new String[listFile.length];
        // Create a String array for FileNameStrings
        FileNameStrings = new String[listFile.length];


        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if(listFile[i].getName().endsWith(extension)) {
                // Get the path of the image file
                FilePathStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
                // Get the name image file
                FileNameStrings[i] = listFile[i].getName();
            }
        }

    }

    // Locate the GridView in gridview_main.xml
    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    grid.setColumnWidth(200);
    grid.setHorizontalSpacing(10);
    grid.setVerticalSpacing(10);
    grid.setNumColumns(2);
    grid.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_SPACING_UNIFORM);
    // Pass String arrays to LazyAdapter Class
    adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this,FilePathStrings, FileNameStrings);
    // Set the LazyAdapter to the GridView
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here's my GridViewAdapter

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Activity activity;
private String[] filepath;
private String[] filename;

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public GridViewAdapter(Activity a, String[] fpath, String[] fname) {
    activity = a;
    filepath = fpath;
    filename = fname;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return filepath.length;

}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
    // Locate the TextView in gridview_item.xml
    TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
    // Locate the ImageView in gridview_item.xml
    ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

    // Set file name to the TextView followed by the position
    text.setText(filename[position]);

    // Decode the filepath with BitmapFactory followed by the position
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath[position]);

    // Set the decoded bitmap into ImageView
    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    return vi;
}

}
```

Comment: You have checked the file extension and got the list of images only. Can you explain what do you want exactly?

Comment: Yeah I checked the file extension but I also adds the video file in the folder to gridview. I used bitmap to show grid image so I cant display the video show blank griditem. I need to display images only. Thanks

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change `listFile = file.listFiles();` to

```
listFile = file.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(extension);
    }
});
```

and in the for-loop, remove the if-condition. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code by doing debug and its working fine but can you show your GridViewAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

`Note` That I have implemented this using `recyclerview and RecyclerView adapter`.

There is no need to insert videos file in separate item place.
Your `ItemHolder` should have two `ImageViews`. One for item and other for `Video Icon`. initially `Video Icon ImageView` visibility would be `Gone or Invisible`. In adapter while binding data just check the path of file. if file's path end with video extension then `Video Icon ImageView` visibility should be changed to visible. I am adding here `XML and item Holder's code`.
XML Code for `Recyleriew` item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cv_status_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@color/colorWhite">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        app:siRadius="6dp"
        app:siBorderColor="#dfdfdf"
        app:siBorderWidth="1dp"
        app:siSquare="true"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_play_icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_transparent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/float_video_play" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_selection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for `ItemHolder` to `BindData`

```
 public void bindData(StatusObject statusObject, int position, int size, boolean selectionMode) {
    super.bindData(statusObject, position, size);
    this.selectionMode = selectionMode;
    if (statusObject.getPath().endsWith(".mp4")) {
        ivPlayIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if (statusObject.getPath().endsWith(".gif")){
        ivPlayIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else ivPlayIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (selectionMode)
        cbSelection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else cbSelection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    cbSelection.setChecked(statusObject.isSelected());
    cbSelection.setClickable(false);
    //        ivStatus.setClipToOutline(true);
    Glide.with(itemView)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(statusObject.getPath())))
            .into(ivStatus);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to play video, then you can **display video thumbnail**  as follows,

```
 Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videofile.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND)
```